# How can I optimize these queries?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, math

Consider the following code snippet:

```
$beat = date('B'); // 1 beat = 86.4 seconds, 1000 beats = 1 day
$total = 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ads WHERE featured = 1;'; // number of featured ads
$current = 'SELECT * FROM ads  WHERE featured = 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . ($beat % $total) . ';'; // current featured ad
```

Basically this cycles trough all the featured ads giving each one of them a beat (86.4 seconds) window where they will be given special highlight, example:

```
$beat       $total          $current

0           3           0
1           3           1
2           3           2
3           3           0
4           3           1
5           3           2
6           3           0
7           3           1
```

This works just fine, however I was wondering if somehow it would be possible to eliminate the need for the $total query and accomplish the same using just one query.

I don't see anyway to do this without using sub-queries but still, I'd like to hear your opinion on this.

Comment: shouldn't the last query select only the ones where featured = 1?

Comment: Given the data set, you could just replace $total with 3.

Maybe you want to give a more varied example?

Comment: @lanut: yeah sorry for that, fixed now.

Comment: @Robert: that's just an example, $total can be any given number of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this is not possible. mysql requires an explicit constant value in LIMIT clauses. you can't put a calculation in a LIMIT clause.

Comment: Can you suggest any other workaround? Doing two queries just for this seems too troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

```
$current = 'SELECT *, FOUND_ROWS(id) as num FROM ads WHERE featured = 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET MOD(' . $beat . ', num)';
```

Comment: Won't the LIMIT 1 clause affect the COUNT function?

Comment: yes, thanks for the hint. One should use FOUND_ROWS() instead

Comment: mysql requires an explicit constant value in LIMIT clauses. you can't put a calculation in a LIMIT clause.

Answer (score -1):

You can't optimize queries. But you can optimize algorithm. Probably, you do need to do this, but... ))

If `$total >= 1000` you will never show some ads. At any case some ads are shown more times then others.

```
long timestamp = ... // standard timestamp in millis
long period = 86400; // millis
long total = ... // you total query
long offset = (timestamp / period) % total;
current = ... // you last query, but with my offset
```

Comment: How does this qualify as an optimization? I still have to do 2 queries and the algorithm is basically the same, I omitted the 1000 limit on $total because it's trivial and solve and would just add noise to the question.

Comment: My first words: "You can't optimize queries". So, it is not optimization.